# Why isn't tflite_support importing in python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, importerror

I installed the tflite_support on my raspberry pi 3 using:
`pip install tflite_support`
it says it has been successfully downloaded I go to python to check by doing

```
$ python3

import tflite_support
```

then this error pops up when I do it in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tflite_support/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata.python import metadata
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_lite_support/metadata/python/metadata.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata.cc.python import _pywrap_metadata_version
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_lite_support/metadata/cc/python/_pywrap_metadata_version.so)
```

but when I do it in the idle this error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/111.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tflite_support
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tflite_support'
```

any idea why is that?

I tried upgrading pip uninstalling and reinstalling tflite_support but I doesn't seem to work.